# How to disable a view in ZF2 without losing the style?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-view

How to disable a view in ZF2 without disabling the style ?
When I did it like this :

```php
$datas = $query->getResult();
$result = new ViewModel(array(
         'datas' => $datas
));
$result->setTerminal(true);

return $result;
```

I just got the data but I lost the style ... thanks.

Comment: You are disabling the *layout*, and the layout is what contains the HTML to load the stylesheet. What are you wanting to happen here?

Comment: It is slightly unclear what you're asking. But as a guess, can't you just assign a blank view to the `ViewModel`? e.g. `$result->setTemplate('my/blank/view');`

Comment: That "blank" view would also render layout if you won't disable it. If this is not set this way it directly will take the following view-path: `MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION`

Comment: @copynpaste I don't understand your comment, but to clarify. I assume OP wants the layout hence this approach. `my/blank/view` is referring to an alias in the `template_map`. If the layout should be blank, then create a specific layout instead..

Comment: But if you call `setTemplate` you only set the Template rendering for this action. This template would normally be rendered IN the layout.

Comment: is that a way to disable the render but keep the style !!

Answer (score 1):

Like Tim in his comment said: The layout contains the styling.

What you could do is to manually `echo` your Helper in this View.

```
echo $this->headLink();
```

For example.

Comment: That one in my answer - if you use it. If not you also simply could add `<link …>` to your View.

Comment: you mean to add the styles i need in the view ... that's it ?

Comment: Right. So this View does not depend on the layout.

Comment: i thought about that , actually i used to do that when i worked with cakePHP framework ... thanks.

Comment: This question is about ZF2, what do you want with cakePHP now?

Comment: So when you are using the Skeleton or another demo project of ZF then in your layout is something like `echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('foo.bar.css')->append…`. There are your Stylesheets added to the helper and printed as links. This will not happen when you disable that layout, so you have to echo them yourself in your view to get the styles.